# CompilerError occurs in Custom Activity - after publish and running manually workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow, custom-actions, sharepoint-designer

**Background**

I have a custom activity that I developed a year ago for a site in SharePoint 2010. The custom activity calls a string method which contains three strings parameters.

Here is the relevant part of the .ACTIONS file:

```
<RuleDesigner Sentence="Search by %1 of profile ID %2 of Type %3 result %4 ">
    <FieldBind Field="Cedula" Text="cedulaUsuario" Id="1" DesignerType="TextArea"/>
    <FieldBind Field="Perfil" Text="idPerfil" Id="2" DesignerType="TextArea"/>
    <FieldBind Field="TipoAsignacion" Text="tipoAsignacion" Id="3" DesignerType="TextArea"/>
    <FieldBind Field="TxtError" Text="txtError" Id="4" DesignerType="ParameterNames"/>
</RuleDesigner>
<Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="Cedula" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="In"/>
    <Parameter Name="Perfil" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="In"/>
    <Parameter Name="TipoAsignacion" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="In"/>
    <Parameter Name="TxtError" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="Out"/>
    <Parameter Name="__Context" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.WorkflowContext, Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions" Direction="In" />
</Parameters>
```

The logic of the custom activity basically makes CRUD operations in a SQL database; *this is not the problem yet*, **the main problem is the execution of the custom activity itself**.

**Current problems**

For an unknown reason, this specific custom activity doesn't work anymore, so, I have to create a new workflow with the custom activity added on it *using SharePoint Designer* (for testing); but when I tried to **publish**, I received this error:

> *Errors where found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were saved but cannot be run.*

In the advanced section appear:

> *Unexpected error on server associating the workflow*

I found on internet<sup>1</sup> that this error occurs because the Temp folder is missing, and it was right. I have to create the Temp folder at `C:\Users\<install>\AppData\Local\` location and inside the Temp folder, create a read-only text file (.txt).

After this change, another problem ocurrs:

Checking the SharePoint logs, it appears that the `TxtError` output parameter isn't generated. Instead a `TxtErrorFlow` appears in the log files:

```
0x1DEC  SharePoint Foundation           Legacy Workflow Infrastructure  72fs    Unexpected  RunWorkflow: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: <Error><CompilerError Line="93" Column="123" Text="Could not find property or event 'TxtErrorFlow' on type 'Glogic.AsignaciondeElementos.Code.AsignacionCode'." /></Error>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPNoCodeXomlCompiler.LoadXomlAssembly(SPWorkflowAssociation association, SPWeb web)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOeHostServices.LoadDeclarativeAssembly(SPWorkflowAssociation association, Boolean fallback)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOeHostServices.CreateInstance(SPWorkflow workflow)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOeEngine.RunWorkflow(SPWorkflowHostService host, SPWorkflow workflow, Collection`1 events, TimeSpan timeOut)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.RunWorkflowElev(SPWorkflow w... f9ef5d9d-fa5f-c053-5312-d7978deecd95
```

*I renamed the `TxtError` variable after bad copy/paste sample code from another current functional custom activity.*

After made the following changes:

- [Rename and rewrite manually](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/89726/35471) the `TxtError` variable in the `FieldBind` and `Parameter` tags in the .ACTIONS file.
- Clean, Build and Deploy in Visual Studio 2012.
- Update .wsp file using PoweShell command.
- Execute `iisreset` command.
- [Clear SPD cache](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache/) of my PC.

Appears the following error in the SharePoint logs:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Glogic.AsignaciondeElementos.Code.AsignacionCode.**get_TxtError()**     at Glogic.AsignaciondeElementos.Code.AsignacionCode.AsignarElementosAlUsuario(String cedulaUsuario, String idPerfil, String tipoAsignacion)     at Glogic.AsignaciondeElementos.Code.AsignacionCode.Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutor`1.Execute(T activity, ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)     at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutorOperation.Run(IWorkflowCoreRuntime workflowCoreRuntime)     at System.Workflow.Runtime.Scheduler.Run()

*(Both errors occurs when the workflow is manually activated).*

Each `publish` event made, deletes temporal files at quoted location at previous lines. I really don't know what else I can do for solve that custom activity renders/build correctly and useful again.

I have found [several](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/119909/35471) [similar](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e94992da-e263-433b-8805-8e6fd7f0f187/workflow-failed-to-run-once-task-overdue?forum=sharepointadmin&prof=required&stoAI=10&wp=MBI_FED_SSL&wlcxt=microsoft$microsoft$microsoft) questions on internet, but the **get_TxtError()** shown in the SharePoint logs continues.

---

<sup>1</sup> I couldn't get the original link source, but the described steps are the relevant part of the source.

Comment: _Since this may not be considered a full answer_ I put it as a comment instead. After deploy, execute IISRESET command and view the .actions file in the WorkFlow mapped folder _for check if has the same structure (no missing spaces, case-sensitive, etc...)_, the custom action now is selectable, however, the previous workflow is lost (I can't select it anymore), so I have to create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following code provided in [this reference](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/logging-uls-sharepoint-2010/) for register info in the SharePoint log files:

```
SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("My Category", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, "unexpected error");
```

I could check the log files and read that the `TxtError` variable is null.

After check this [reference in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.workflow.componentmodel.dependencyproperty(v=vs.90).aspx), it seems that the `TxtError` parameter needs an additional property declared in code, that property is called `PropertyMetadata`.

So, my DependencyProperty variable was:

```
public static DependencyProperty TxtErrorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TxtErrorFlow", typeof(string), typeof(MyClassSample));
```

Adding the `PropertyMetadata` property, the result is:

```
public static DependencyProperty TxtErrorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TxtErrorFlow", typeof(string), typeof(MyClassSample), new PropertyMetadata(""));
```

After following these steps:

- Clean, Build and Deploy solution (in Visual Studio 2012).
- Update .wsp file using PoweShell command.
- Execute `iisreset /noforce` command.

The custom activity and the complete workflow worked again.

---

**Side notes**

During my tests, I lost some workflows which contains my custom activity; in SharePoint Designer, after selecting the workflow the screen shows:

*Image taken from [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/156427/35471).*
[image: SharePoint Designer workflow not showing]

And I couldn't recover those workflows. As an advice, I suggest:

- ALWAYS make a backup of your original workflow and a copy.
- If you need work in the same workflow, use the copy instead; otherwise, create a new workflow with the *log to history list* action and the custom activity only.